# Using Vba find the attributes used inside a HTML tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm parsing HTML code through vba. Instead of reading the HTML file, im getting the object of already opened IE and parsing the HTML.
Now, I can get the tag names and their attribute values. But I cant able to find the attributes that are used.
For example,

```
META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-1"
```

In this META tag, i can get the attribute values by using

```
For Each a In ie.document.all.tags("META")
 Debug.Print a.getAttribute("content")
Next
```

But I need the "HTTP-EQUIV", "CONTENT", "CHARSET" and not its values. Is there any way to get the attibutes that are used in a tag ? I'm trying for a long time. Couldn't succeed.

Comment: have you tried looping over `a.attributes` ?

Comment: @Tim Williams I just tried and I can get the attributes. Thank you. But I'm getting all the attributes instead of, what have been used. I looped like this `For Each q In a.Attributes
            Debug.Print q.Name & q.Value
        Next`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the element attributes:

```
Dim a
For Each a In ie.document.all.tags("META").attributes
 Debug.Print a.value
Next
```

EDIT: all possible attributes are listed, even unused ones.  I think that's just how it works in IE - you will have to filter out the ones which were actually used by checking to see if there is a value, or maybe try examining each attribute's `specified` property value.